# How do you enable/disable button in parent component from a change in a form in a child component without losing form data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state, react-hook-form

I am updating a form nested in a custom modal component, where the submit button is in the parent. The submit button needs to be disabled until a checkbox in the form is selected. Passing a method down to set state of button is rerendering all child components and I lose my input values. What is the best way to enable/disable button and save the state of my form?

```
const CreateGroupModal = () => {
  const [discardGroupsModalOpen, setDiscardGroupsModalOpen] = useState(false);
  const [submitDisabled, setSubmitDisabled] = useState(true);
  const formRef = useRef();

  const disableSubmit = disabled => {
    setSubmitDisabled(disabled);
  };

  const callSubmit = () => {
    formRef.current.dispatchEvent(new Event('submit', { cancelable: true }));
  };

  return (
    <FullScreenModal
      onSubmit={callSubmit}
      submitButtonProps={{
        disabled: submitDisabled,
        tooltipProps: {
          title: `${state ? 'At least one result must be selected' : ''}`,
        },
      }}
    >
      <CreateGroupForm disableSubmit={disableSubmit} formRef={formRef} />
    </FullScreenModal>
  );
};
```

```
const CreateGroupForm = ({ formRef, disableSubmit }) => {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    setValue,
    errors,
    clearErrors,
    setError,
  } = useForm({ mode: 'all', validateCriteriaMode: 'all' });

  const handleCheckboxSelection = selectedResultsCount => {
    disableSubmit(disableSubmit(selectedResultsCount === 0));
  };

  return (
    <form id="createGroupForm" ref={formRef} onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <input
        name="name"
        ref={register({
          required: true,
        })}
      />
      <div>
        <MaterialTableComponent
          handleCheckboxSelection={handleCheckboxSelection}
        />
      </div>
      )}
    </form>
  );
};
```

Comment: values shouldn't be lost even when rerendering, it seems your form is actually being remounted, can you confirm that with the react profiler or putting a console.log in an useEffect inside your form? `useEffect(() => { return () => console.log('unmounting...'); })`

Comment: @diedu yes it seems it is being unmounted when setSubmitDisabled is being called

Comment: probably is something you need to fix inside your `FullScreenModal` component, avoid remounting its children

Comment: @diedu Thank you that was it. That is a reusable modal component that we have used so I assumed I was overlooking something in my own structure, but there was a functional component used by the children , in the function body for FullScreenModal, causing the unmounting of the children.

Comment:  you can add the answer with the details and accept it or just close the question

Comment: can you post the solution to the community?

Answer (score 0):

The button component used in the reusable modal had its styling code saved in a constant in the body of the functional component, when the disabled state would change, it would rerender the component and all the children.